# Unity Admob EventHandler doesn't get called on real device(android)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, admob

In my app,
if I press a button, interstitial ad appear.
And I want to make the scene changes when I close the interstitial ad.
It works perfectly on emulator. But on real device, `OnAdFullScreenContentClosed` doesn't get called.
The ad works, but scene doesn't change on real device.
Can you help me...?

Here is my code.

```
public class Mymanager : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool isloaded = false;
    private InterstitialAd _interstitialAd;
    string sceneN = "Scene0";

    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        private string _adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        private string _adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX";
    #else
        private string _adUnitId = "unused";
    #endif

    void Start()
    {
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
        LoadInterstitialAd();
    }

    public void onClickButton()
    {
        if(isloaded){
            ShowInterstitialAd();
        } else {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneN);
        }
    }

    public void LoadInterstitialAd()
    {
        if (_interstitialAd != null)
        {
            _interstitialAd.Destroy();
            _interstitialAd = null;
        }

        var adRequest = new AdRequest();

        InterstitialAd.Load(_adUnitId, adRequest,
            (InterstitialAd ad, LoadAdError error) =>
            {
                if (error != null || ad == null)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("interstitial ad failed to load an ad " +
                            "with error : " + error);
                    isloaded = false;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    isloaded = true;
                }

                Debug.Log("Interstitial ad loaded with response : "
                    + ad.GetResponseInfo());

                _interstitialAd = ad;
            });

        RegisterEventHandlers(_interstitialAd);
    }

    public void ShowInterstitialAd()
    {
        if (_interstitialAd != null && _interstitialAd.CanShowAd())
        {
            _interstitialAd.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Interstitial ad is not ready yet.");
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneN);
        }
    }

    private void RegisterEventHandlers(InterstitialAd interstitialAd)
    {

        interstitialAd.OnAdPaid += (AdValue adValue) =>
        {
            Debug.Log(String.Format("Interstitial ad paid {0} {1}.",
                adValue.Value,
                adValue.CurrencyCode));
        };

        interstitialAd.OnAdImpressionRecorded += () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Interstitial ad recorded an impression.");
        };

        interstitialAd.OnAdClicked += () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Ad: Clicked");
        };

        interstitialAd.OnAdFullScreenContentOpened += () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Ad: Opend");
        };

        interstitialAd.OnAdFullScreenContentClosed += () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Ad: Closed");
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneN);

        };

        interstitialAd.OnAdFullScreenContentFailed += (AdError error) =>
        {
            Debug.LogError("Ad: Failed" +
                        "with error : " + error);
            SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneN);
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes here.
First one you should not load any ad before initializing admob as it stated here.
https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/quick-start

To fix this you should put your LoadInterstitialAd function inside the initialization callback.

```
    MobileAds.Initialize((initStatus) =>
    {
        LoadInterstitialAd();
    });
```

The second issue where you register event handlers. You need to register them after loading the ad, not before, like this:

```
InterstitialAd.Load(_adUnitId, adRequest,
        (InterstitialAd ad, LoadAdError error) =>
        {
            if (error != null || ad == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("interstitial ad failed to load an ad " +
                        "with error : " + error);
                isloaded = false;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                isloaded = true;
            }

            Debug.Log("Interstitial ad loaded with response : "
                + ad.GetResponseInfo());
      
            _interstitialAd = ad;
            RegisterEventHandlers(_interstitialAd);
        });
```

Comment: You saved me. It works! Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem, coincidentally I was having trouble with admob in the past and made the same mistake as you did.

Comment: @JosephStar And if I am using more than one Interstitial Ads? Should I create more than one RegisterEventHandler or can I use only one RegisterEventHandler to listen the Interstitials Ads Events?